# Node.js JSON parsing

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have a JSON string that looks like this:

```
{
  "resultType" : "history",
  "currentTime" : "2011-10-22T15:46:00+00:00",
  "columns" : ["date","orders","quantity","low","high","average"],
  "rowsets" : [
    {
      "generatedAt" : "2011-10-22T15:42:00+00:00",
      "rows" : [
        ["2011-12-03T00:00:00+00:00",40,40,1999,499999.99,35223.50],
        ["2011-12-02T00:00:00+00:00",83,252,9999,11550,11550]
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Every time I try to parse it, I use code like this:

```
var data = JSON.parse(json);
console.log(data);
```

And the following is what is printed to the console:

```
{
  "resultType" : "history",
  "currentTime" : "2011-10-22T15:46:00+00:00",
  "columns" : ["date","orders","quantity","low","high","average"],
  "rowsets" : [
    {
      "generatedAt" : "2011-10-22T15:42:00+00:00",
      "rows" : [Object]
    }
  ]
}
```

I've tried a couple of things, but how can I get the data in the `rows` field? After parsing, the console just shows `[Object]`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The output you're seeing is just the way it's being displayed. If you access `data.rowsets[0].rows`, you can see that the JSON was indeed successfully parsed. You can also use `util.inspect()` when specifying the `depth` property to tell Node.js to recurse deeper when formatting the object.

Here is an example using `util.inspect()`:

```
var data = JSON.parse(json);
// a null depth means to recurse indefinitely
console.log(util.inspect(data, { depth: null }));
```

Comment: You would access it using `data.rowsets[0].rows`. `rowsets` is an array.

Answer (score 0):

Have tested your code. It's fine.

```
   var a = {
      "resultType" : "history",
      "currentTime" : "2011-10-22T15:46:00+00:00",
      "columns" : ["date","orders","quantity","low","high","average"],
      "rowsets" : [
        {
          "generatedAt" : "2011-10-22T15:42:00+00:00",
          "rows" : [
            ["2011-12-03T00:00:00+00:00",40,40,1999,499999.99,35223.50],
            ["2011-12-02T00:00:00+00:00",83,252,9999,11550,11550]
          ]
        }
      ]
    }

    var util = require('util');

    console.log(util.inspect(a.rowsets[0].rows, { showHidden: true, depth: null }));
```